# Can't create new work item type states through Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Been writing a Python code to automate a few setups of the organization creation process in my company, but I can’t create new states in some of the work item types. And, in a odd manner, this seems to happen only in work item types that were already in the system.
Here’s the full code:

```
import base64
from os import environ as env
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
import contador

load_dotenv()

AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT = env['AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT']

patEncoded = base64.b64encode((":" + AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT).encode()).decode()

organization = 'dummy-name'

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': f'Basic {patEncoded}'
}

def getProcessID(testName, organization, headers):
  global contador
  getUrl = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/process/processes?api-version=7.1-preview.1'
  while True:
    try:
        req = requests.get(getUrl, headers=headers)
        break
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
      contador.contador += 1
      print(f"Erro de timeout número {contador.contador}. Tentando novamente...")
      time.sleep(10)
  json_object = json.loads(req.text)
  reqTextSize = len(json_object['value'])
  for i in range(reqTextSize):
    name = json_object['value'][i]['name']
    if name == testName:
      processId = json_object['value'][i]['id']
  return processId

def criarEstados(tipo, processId, organization, headers):
    tabelaRefNames = getWorkItemTypes(processId, organization, headers)
    filePath = "printDebug.txt"
    if tipo == 'Agile':
        tabelaEstados = pd.read_excel('kanban.xlsx')
    elif tipo == 'Scrum':
        tabelaEstados = pd.read_excel('scrum.xlsx')
    tabelaEstados = tabelaEstados.merge(tabelaRefNames, left_on="workItemType", right_on="originName", how='left')
    tabelaEstadosDict = tabelaEstados.to_dict()
    tabelaEstadosDictSize = len(tabelaEstadosDict["workItemType"])
    linhas = []
    with open(filePath, 'w') as printDebug:
            for i in range(tabelaEstadosDictSize):
                workItemType = tabelaEstadosDict["workItemType"][i]
                witRefName = tabelaEstadosDict["referenceName"][i]
                name = tabelaEstadosDict["originName"][i]
                color = tabelaEstadosDict["color"][i]
                stateCategory = tabelaEstadosDict["stateCategory"][i]
                referenceName = f"{witRefName} foi passado\n"
                status = criarEstado(processId, organization, headers, witRefName, name, color, stateCategory)
                resultState = f'Estado {name} no Work Item Type {workItemType} deu este retorno:\n'
                linhas.extend([resultState, referenceName, f'{status}\n'])
                printDebug.writelines(linhas)
                linhas.clear()
    print("Debug finalizado.")

def main():
  testName = "Processo-Kanban"
  processId = getProcessID(testName, organization, headers)
  criarEstados('Agile', processId, organization, headers)

main()
```

```
For Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug as witRefName:
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "VS402805: Cannot find work item type with reference name 'Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug' in process named '07c52453-a09e-4f35-a0f1-40bdb972afb9'.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
  "typeKey": "ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 3200
}
For Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.UserStory as witRefName:
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "VS402805: Cannot find work item type with reference name 'Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.UserStory' in process named '07c52453-a09e-4f35-a0f1-40bdb972afb9'.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
  "typeKey": "ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 3200
}
For Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Task  as witRefName:
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "VS402805: Cannot find work item type with reference name 'Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Task' in process named '07c52453-a09e-4f35-a0f1-40bdb972afb9'.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
  "typeKey": "ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 3200
}
For Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Epic as witRefName:
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "VS402805: Cannot find work item type with reference name 'Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Epic' in process named '07c52453-a09e-4f35-a0f1-40bdb972afb9'.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
  "typeKey": "ProcessWorkItemTypeDoesNotExistException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 3200
}
```

I've succeeded with this script to create the work item state, but only for custom work item types.
And also I'm able to create new work item type states through the web UI (organization settings in Azure Devops).

Also, once I added the states to the Bug work item type through the web UI, the code captured the witRefName as “Processo-Kanban.Bug”, and no longer as “Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug”.

The same happened to the Epic work item type. And, for both, my code seemed to start working as intended.

So is it possible that the witRefName should be something along the lines of f"{processName}.{workItemName)?

Anyway, could anyone please help me?

I've tried different ways to obtain the witRefName, and they all failed.
Code's above.

Comment: Hi there, Have you got a chance to check my answer below? Hope it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that you were trying to add new state for the work item type in the **default** process. Kindly note that to customize the work tracking system, you need to customize an `inherited` process.

Here is my work flow for your refence to create new state for the `Bug` in one of my inherited processes `AgileInherited`.

1. Get(list) the `processId` of the target inherited process via [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP);

   ```
   GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes?api-version=7.2-preview.2
   ```

   `Agile` is one of the 4 **default** processes, while `AgileInherited` is the customized inherited process.

   ```
   …
           {
               "typeId": "adcc42ab-9882-485e-a3ed-7678f01f66bc",
               "name": "Agile",
               "referenceName": null,
               "description": "This template is flexible and will work great for most teams using Agile planning methods, including those practicing Scrum.",
               "parentProcessTypeId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
               "isEnabled": true,
               "isDefault": false,
               "customizationType": "system"
           },
           {
               "typeId": "f37a3e41-85fc-4cbd-8a14-5b97df442661",
               "name": "AgileInherited",
               "referenceName": "Inherited.f37a3e4185fc4cbd8a145b97df442661",
               "description": "Inherited process from Agile",
               "parentProcessTypeId": "adcc42ab-9882-485e-a3ed-7678f01f66bc",
               "isEnabled": true,
               "isDefault": true,
               "customizationType": "inherited"
           },
   …
   ```
2. Get(list) the `referenceName` of target work item type via [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/work-item-types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP);

   ```
   GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workitemtypes?api-version=7.2-preview.2
   ```

   Per the `Bug` work item type in my `InheritedAgile` process, its `witRefName` as well as `referenceName` is `AgileInherited.Bug`;

   ```
   …
           {
               "referenceName": "AgileInherited.Bug",
               "name": "Bug",
               "description": "Describes a divergence between required and actual behavior, and tracks the work done to correct the defect and verify the correction.",
               "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/f37a3e41-85fc-4cbd-8a14-5b97df442661/workItemTypes/AgileInherited.Bug",
               "customization": "inherited",
               "color": "CC293D",
               "icon": "icon_insect",
               "isDisabled": false,
               "inherits": "Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug"
           },
   …
   ```
3. Create new state `Ready to test` for the `Bug` in my `AgileInherited` process via [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/states/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP);

   ```
   POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/states?api-version=7.2-preview.1
   ```

   **My Sample**

   ```
   POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processdefinitions/f37a3e41-85fc-4cbd-8a14-5b97df442661/workItemTypes/AgileInherited.Bug/states?api-version=7.2-preview.1

   {
     "name": "Ready to test",
     "stateCategory": "InProgress",
     "color": "207752",
     "order": null
   }
   ```
4. The new state is visible in `Bug` of `AgileInherited` process.
   [image]

Hope the information could help resolve your concerns.

Comment: Hi, actually I was trying to create the states in an inherited process, as you explained yourself. The lines 
```
if tipo == 'Agile':
        tabelaEstados = pd.read_excel('kanban.xlsx')
elif tipo == 'Scrum':
        tabelaEstados = pd.read_excel('scrum.xlsx')
```
actually are testing if I created a inherited process from Agile or Scrum.

Comment: Hi @fcoalcantarajr, however, as observed in the `reference name Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug` from the response, it was a workitem in the default process. With the help of step 2 in the above answer, we can get the reference name of the workitem in our inherited process, which should be like `"referenceName": "AgileInherited.Bug",` and then create custom state for that work item type. Is it what concerns you?

Comment: I eventually got to that.
When creating the process via API, Azure DevOps doesn't create the inherited work item types. I added a piece of code to ensure the inherited work item types are being created, and now I can get to the names of "referenceName": "AgileInherited.Bug". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to know you managed to get that. By the way, would you consider accepting this answer, which may help others with similar concerns. Thx.